# How to group by hour in HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following table in HANA :

```
vehicle_id    time                          roaming_time        parking_time
    1          Sep 01,2016 3:09:03 AM            3                   9
    2          Sep 01,2016 3:12:03 AM            6                   8
    1          Sep 01,2016 9:10:03 AM            10                  6
    4          Sep 01,2016 10:09:03 AM           9                   3
    1          Sep 01,2016 10:10:03 AM           10                  10
    4          Sep 01,2016 12:09:03 AM           3                   9
```

from these information I wanted to know that what is the sum of `roaming_time` and sum of `parking_time` for each hour from all the vehicles and want the output in the format:

```
time                         roaming_time     parking_time
____                         _____________    ____________
2016-09-01 00:00:00                3                9
2016-09-01 01:00:00                6                8
2016-09-01 02:00:00                9                6
2016-09-01 03:00:00                3                6
2016-09-01 04:00:00                12               3
2016-09-01 05:00:00                15               8
2016-09-01 06:00:00                18               4
2016-09-01 07:00:00                8                3
2016-09-01 08:00:00                9                4
2016-09-01 09:00:00                6                6
2016-09-01 10:00:00                6                9
........
2016-09-01 23:00:00                3                12
```

I need  to group the following query  which gives all the sum  by hour wise and get the expected result:

```
select sum(roaming_time) as roaming_time,sum(parking_time) as parking_time 
          from time>='2016-09-01 00:00:00'
               time>='2016-09-01 23:59:59'
```

I do not know how to do the grouping by hour in HANA. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method . . . it converts the time to a date and hour format:

```
select to_varchar(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), hour(time),
       sum(roaming_time) as roaming_time, sum(parking_time) as parking_time from t
group by date(time), hour(time)
order by to_varchar(time, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), hour(time);
```

Comment: When I execute the query `select date(time) from t` it shows invalid name of function.but  `select hour(time) from t` works fine in hana

Comment: @Lars Br. Any idea Why is it happening like this?

Comment: @Josh . . . I think I was thinking of the `to_date()` function, but `to_char()` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `group by` clause with [`SERIES_ROUND()`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/435ec476ab494ad6b8409f22abec13fe.html). Avoid `date()` and `hour()` and similar data/time functions on large data sets as they tend to be slower.

```
select SERIES_ROUND(time, 'INTERVAL 1 HOUR') as time,
       sum(roaming_time) as roaming_time, sum(parking_time) as parking_time from t
group by SERIES_ROUND(time, 'INTERVAL 1 HOUR')
order by SERIES_ROUND(time, 'INTERVAL 1 HOUR');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to convert it to a string, especially if no further time calculations are required.
This could look like this:

```
select to_varchar(time, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24') as parking_hour ,
       sum(roaming_time) as roaming_time, sum(parking_time) as parking_time from t
group by to_varchar(time, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24') as parking_hour
order byto_varchar(time, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24') as parking_hour;
```